# Awstats: awstats_buildstaticpages.pl only builds 1 report, not full reports

Tags: nginx, awstats

I remember running this command before and it used to build all the pages, but now that I use it again it only builds the main page.

(new lines for readability)

```
/usr/share/awstats/tools/awstats_buildstaticpages.pl 
-update 
-config=mydomain.com 
-dir=/var/www/awstats/mydomain.com/ 
-awstatsprog=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

This is my `awstats.mydomain.com.conf`:

```
LogFile="/etc/nginx/logs/mydomain.com.log"
LogFormat=1
SiteDomain="mydomain.com"
DNSLookup=0
DirData="/var/lib/awstats/mydomain.com/"
HostAliases="mydomain.com"
```

The only file I get is `awstats.mydomain.com.html`

Does anyone know what is causing this? or am I missing something else?

I'm using Debian Squeeze x86

Comment: Why do you nulling the script output? Try to remove `>/dev/null` from your command and see what it returns.

Comment: @hangover It only removes the messages of "1 files built", etc. I removed it anyway but the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `awstats_buildstaticpages.pl` script doesn't replace `Show*` config options with its default values. So in order to all statistic files could be formed, you must determine (or uncomment default) values for options in awstats config file.

These are:

```
ShowSummary=UVPHB
ShowMonthStats=UVPHB
ShowDaysOfMonthStats=VPHB
ShowDaysOfWeekStats=PHB
ShowHoursStats=PHB
ShowDomainsStats=PHB
ShowHostsStats=PHBL
ShowRobotsStats=HBL
ShowSessionsStats=1
ShowPagesStats=PBEX
ShowFileTypesStats=HB
ShowOSStats=1
ShowBrowsersStats=1
ShowOriginStats=PH
ShowKeyphrasesStats=1
ShowKeywordsStats=1
ShowMiscStats=a
ShowHTTPErrorsStats=1
ShowFlagLinks=""
ShowLinksOnUrl=1
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, so I need to add all those setting in order to generate all the pages? The docs and even tutorials doesn't tell anything about that.

Comment: It looks like it is. I learned this by practical, it was not described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems these values must be in the top file. If they are only in awstats.conf.local then they are not picked up.

Comment: I checked their perl code, you can also put these 'Show*' lines into awstats.your-site-name.conf